# JUnit: Add two duplicated fixtures to some method

Tags: junit

Hi I want to test duplication by adding same fixture more than twice. It could be the code below:

```
@Test(expected=DuplicationException.class)
public void saveFailedWithDuplicatedAccount(){
    memberServiceImpl.save(member);
    memberServiceImpl.save(member);
}
```

but I don't know how to deal with Mockito coding - like using when(), verify(). Since I am new to mockito, and I have got nothing found in the Google, so is there any example code to check duplicating addition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save state somewhere.
It may be some kind of internal storage or real database.

And you can extract logic for searching duplicates and mock that.
For example:

```java
Test(expected = DuplicationException.class)
    public void saveFailedWithDuplicatedAccount() {
        DuplicateService duplicateServiceMock = Mockito.mock(DuplicateService.class);
        memberServiceImpl.setDuplicateService(duplicateServiceMock);
        memberServiceImpl.save(member);

        Mockito.when(duplicateServiceMock.isDuplicate(member)).thenReturn(true);
        memberServiceImpl.save(member);
    }

public class DuplicateAccountService {
    public boolean isDuplicateAccount(String login) {
        return false; // Some logic for find duplicates
    }
}
```